# The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I AM  trying to create a login page with flutter and firebase the navigator worked properly in all files but when coming to this page it shows an error at the context in the navigator 
the error is
'The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. 
the following are the details of my flutter version:
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.2
  oktoast:
  firebase_auth: ^0.5.20
please help me to solve this

```
 import 'package:path/path.dart';
    import 'package:codej/effects.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:oktoast/oktoast.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

    class Auth extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
    _AuthState createState() => new _AuthState();
    }

    class _AuthState extends State<Auth>{

    String _email, _password;
    final GlobalKey<FormState> formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Authentication"),
        ),
        // TODO: implement build
    body: Form(
      key: formkey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
    TextFormField(
      validator: (input){
        if(input.isEmpty){
          showToastWidget(Text("please enter your user name"));
        }
      },
      onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Email'
      ),
    ),
    TextFormField(
      validator: (input){
        if(input.length < 6){
          showToastWidget(Text("please enter your password atleast 6 characters"));
        }
      },
      onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Password'
      ),
      obscureText: true,
    ),
    RaisedButton(onPressed: (){

    },
    child: Text("Sign in"),)
        ],
      )),
        );
      }
      void signinAuth() async{
        final formState = formkey.currentState;
        if(formState.validate()){
        formState.save();
        try{
     FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomNav())); //BottomNav loacted in other file  
        }catch(e){
          print(e.message);
        }

        }

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working on my pc, so it is version problem. Try updating your flutter and dart sdk, if this is not the solution for you, just pass BuildContext to your signinAuth like this

```
void signinAuth(BuildContext context) async {
    final formState = formkey.currentState;
    if (formState.validate()) {
      formState.save();
      try {
        FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    BottomNav())); //BottomNav loacted in other file
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Actually I think using **(BuildContext context)** in your method is the solution, I don’t think it’s related to version of the SDK.

Comment: But it worked fine in my pc, did it just to pass this error

Comment: Yes I guess because you wrote method differently, your method has parameter **context** and I think that’s the reason it’s working.

Comment: my function didn't have context parameter btw, being in extend state class enough for context, no need to pass it as parameter (in my version currently 1.14.6 and channel beta)

Comment: Interesting, it never works for me, is it on the new update?, I usually don’t risk of not using it even if works without it.

Comment: try environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: @RaviMunnangi try flutter packages get and restart your program